# Recent publication and special issues

Tags: publications, ieee, special-issue

I'm looking to know how to get notifications when there is a recent publication (in IEEE Transaction Journal and MDPI Energies). Moreover, If there are any special issues (Smart grid or something related to it) I want to be aware of these. Can someone guide how to get notified with these two journals?

P.s: (Although I have accounts in these)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Journals usually have a RSS feed available that tracks the current ToC. As for Special issues, you would have to subscribe (or just create an account) to a publisher. This way, I regularly receive updates via email on special issues from parent publishing houses of journals where I published / reviewed (think Elsevier, Springer, IEEE xplore, etc).

Comment: That's a very good point, however, the issue is that then there is no filter it means you can receive on each and every topic related to you or not. As I said, I already have that account. Thank you anyways

Comment: To a degree that is true (and Flyto said as much in his answer), however, in my experience, you don't get that much spam and it is easy to quickly sift through in order to identify whether there is something interesting. The "problem" with the special issues is that they are often an amalgam of different topics and actively encourage people from other disciplines to participate. In other words, a physics special issue might not be considered spam by a computer scientist, because his work might be related. That is part of the reason why the special issue invitations are broadcasted.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to get MDPI to notify you of upcoming special issues without knowing about everything else they publish.

If you're looking to submit to those special issues, I recommend looking for subject-specific communities (e.g. mailing lists or similar) that people might advertise calls for papers to.

If you're simply looking to read them, I suggest setting up some good Google Scholar alerts around the subjects; if you get these right then as well as giving you interesting articles from all over the place, they will tend to show up multiple articles from the same special issues.